# Summing every row of dataframe with a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sum every row of a dataframe with a series.

I have a dataframe with [107 rows and 42 columns] and a series of length 42. I would like to sum every row with the series such that every column in the dataframe would have the same number added to it. I tried df.add(series) but the result was a dataframe with 107 rows and 84 columns with all NaN values.

For example

```
dataframe:
Index a b c 
d     1 2 3
e     4 5 6
f     7 8 9
g     0 0 0

series: 1 2 3
```

result would be

```
Index a  b  c 
d     2  4  6
e     5  7  9
f     8 10 12
g     1  2  3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) or `+` with numpy array if differet index values like columns names:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
df = df.add(s.to_numpy())
#alternative
#df = df + s.to_numpy()
print (df)
   a   b   c
d  2   4   6
e  5   7   9
f  8  10  12
g  1   2   3
```

---

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
              
s.index = df.columns
df = df.add(s)
#alternative
#df = df + s
print (df)
   a   b   c
d  2   4   6
e  5   7   9
f  8  10  12
g  1   2   3
```